# Windows 7 Professional 64 bits - Error in Ssl Connection for Event Notification Application

Tags: openssl, wamp, windows-7-x64

When I install SSL for windows with wamp.

I downloaded the binary from https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html 
and install with this version Win64 OpenSSL v1.0.2h.

After that when I start the window, this notification always show up.

[image]

Thank you for advance for your help.

Comment: All you need to do is copy the `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll` from the openssl install's `bin` folder to the `\wamp\bin\php\php{version}` folder and then restart wampserver

Comment: I did that and it stills show the same error, do you have any idea what could potential cause this issue? Thank you.

Comment: Ok so now rebuild the symlinks by doing `right click wampserver icon -> refresh`